# Values of one column appears in another column with read_csv Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a trouble when I'm using .read_csv(data.csv,dtype = str),

When I run the code, for some reason, some  few values of one columns appears in other columns, like that:

Data.csv before reading:

```
Id Info1 Info2 Info3
01 a1    b1     c1
02 a2    b2     c2
03 a3    b3     c3
04 a4    b4     c4
```

Command used to read on Python:

import pandas as pd

Data = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', dtype=str)

Data.csv after the read_csv command:

```
Id Info1 Info2 Info3
01 a1    b1     c1
02 a2    b2     c2
03 a3    b3     c3
04       a4     b4
```

It's sounds like for some rows it's not reading the correct column value and putting another in the place.

Someone can help me with that, please?

Comment: This would be hard to help with without seeing the literal data. I don't suppose you could put the actual data in the post?

Comment: It may help to double check you are using the correct encoding.

Comment: Sure I will edit the post

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn and@owen I think i found what was happing, it was an Excel trouble because of to many rows ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did what you did and everything is fine

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('Book1.csv', dtype=str)
```

[image]

Double checking your data may help